# How to choose a new HVAC unit

Tags: hvac

If you lived in Chattanooga TN  and had to purchase a brand new HVAC unit what would you?
What unit would you purchase and what is the approximate price?
I need to replace my upstairs unit it looks like the insulation has failed and its condensing water on the outside creating mold. The inside of the unit is mold free.

Comment: Have you checked if it can be fix?  Usually cheaper than a new unit, unless it needed major repairs or very old.  Price questions are a no-no on here since they can be so different from place and time.  Would also depend on the size of your place.  Insulation usually does not fail, it might get moved out place or wet, but it should not fail.

Comment: Price questions and product recommendations are off topic here, and the rest of the question is too broad. We know _nothing_ about your home. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

### Now is the time to get a heat pump

In fact I shopped for an A/C replacement last year. They wanted to shove me into "That 70's air conditioner" with a pathetic 13 SEER efficiency.  Modern heat pumps do A/C at as much as 38 SEER (that's 3 times more efficient).

But heat pumps have another trick: they can HEAT.  And, *they can heat more efficiently than gas. In Chicago.*   Even better for you in two ways: First, Tennessee is warmer than Chicago so heat pumps work even better. And second, you have cheaper electricity thanks to TVA, so anything that makes your heat less gassy and more sparky is a good thing.

Even more, in the future, the outlook for gas is all bad, and the outlook for electricity - well, we're seeing a lot of really neat tech coming up the pipe that will probably *over-solve* a number of today's problems, and make electricity rather reasonable - especially when you can schedule your HVAC advantageously.

There's an excellent series of videos on this from a technologist.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI (why now)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43XKfuptnik (doing it)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto (first in series)

Don't whole house A/Cs need huge generators though?  Good question.  Heat pumps are far more efficient to begin with, and they use an inverter drive for "soft start". This greatly reduces the size of the generator they need.  In fact, they're the darling of people who run off-grid solar/battery because efficiency is everything there.

Comment: Generators? Where did that come from?

Comment: @isherwood it's a common objection. Gas furnaces are easier to run on generator than "that 70s A/C", and so proposing they use an A/C for heat makes some nervous.